# Массивы и как их использовать?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int sample[10];
int t;
for(t = 0; t < 10; t++) sample[t] = t;
for(t = 0; t < 10; t++)
    cout<< "Sample[" << t <<"]:" << sample[t] << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Почему при вводе массива мы используем два раза "For" и с одной и той де переменной?И как мы присваиваем sample значение "t"?Тут еще один вопрос:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int sample[10];
int t;
for(t=0; t<10; t+=2) sample[t] = t;
for(t=0; t<10; t++)
    cout<< "Sample[" << t <<"]:" << sample[t] << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
Sample[0]:-858993460
Sample[1]:-858993460
Sample[2]:2
Sample[3]:-858993460
Sample[4]:4
Sample[5]:-858993460
Sample[6]:6
Sample[7]:-858993460
Sample[8]:8
Sample[9]:-858993460
```

Тут тоже самое,только прибавляется по 2,а не по одному,как раньше.Почему выводятся числа,остаток от которых равен 0?Я понимаю,это из-за того,что мы поставили "t=0;t<10;t+=2",но как это работает?Можете объяснить про два куска программы?

Comment: Во втором случае - *Не верю! (с) Станиславский* - `Sample[0]` должно вывести как 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поочередно...

> Почему при вводе массива мы используем два раза "For" и с одной и той де переменной?

Потому что в первом цикле присваиваем значения элементам массива, а во втором выводим.

> И как мы присваиваем sample значение "t"

```
sample[t] = t;
```

> Почему выводятся числа, остаток от которых равен 0?

Потому что в цикле выполняется присваивание при `t` равном 0, 2, 4, 6, 8... Для остальных значений индекса в массиве остается мусор.

> как это работает

```
for(a;b;c) d;
```

работает так:

```
1.   a;
2.   проверка b. Если истинно - переход к строке 3, если ложно - к строке 6.
3.   d;
4.   c;
5.   переход к строке 2.
6.   выполнение программы дальше...
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за пояснительный ответ!